# Принцип расстановки ударений

Tags: фонетика

Я с глупым вопросом о принципах постановки ударений. А именно: почему "купИла", но "продалА"? Так сложилось или тут действует какое-то правило?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ударение в русском языке разноместное (в разных словах может падать на разные слоги) и подвижное (в одном и том же слове при формоизменении ударение передвигается). Строгих принципов нет. Тем не менее, некоторые общие  закономерности наблюдаются.

В глаголах прошедшего времени ударение обычно падает на тот же слог, что и в инфинитиве: сидЕть — сидЕла, стонАть — стонАла, прЯтатъ — прЯтала, начинАть — начинАла. Вместе с тем группа употребительных глаголов (около 300) подчиняется другому правилу: ударение в форме женского рода переходит на окончание, а в остальных формах остаётся на основе. Это глаголы брать, быть, взять, вить, врать, гнать, дать, ждать, жить, звать, лгать, лить, пить, рвать и др. Рекомендуется говорить: жить — жил — жИло — жИли — жилА; ждать — ждал — ждАло — ждАли — ждалА; лить — лил — лИло — лИли — лилА. Так же произносятся и производные глаголы (прожить, забрать, допить, пролить и т. п.).

Исключение составляют слова с приставкой вы-, которая принимает ударение на себя: вЫжитъ — вЫжила, вЫлитъ —вЫлила, вЫзвать — вЫзвала.

У глаголов класть, красть, слать, послать ударение в форме женского рода прошедшего времени остаётся на основе: крАла, слАла, послАла, стлАла.

И ещё одна закономерность. Довольно часто в возвратных глаголах (в сравнении с невозвратными) ударение в форме прошедшего времени переходит на окончание: начАтъся — началсЯ, началАсь, началОсь, началИсь; принЯться — принялсЯ, принялАсь, принялОсь, принялИсь.

Таким образом, купИть - купИла  (ударение в прошедшем времени, как в инфинитиве)
Продать - продала, так как от односложного дать - далА - по другому правилу, которому подчиняются около 300 общеупотребительных слов.